# how to set imageSearch is default and set results to 20 items in Google CustomSearch

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

I search around but can not found any topics likes my title to post my answer so I create my own and post my working answer to anyone need this.
Because I working on it all a day long so I think it can help someone!

```
google.load('search', '1');

google.setOnLoadCallback(
        function () {
            var customSearchOptions = {
                enableImageSearch: true,
                defaultToImageSearch: true,
                imageSearchOptions: {
                    resultSetSize: 20,
                    RESTRICT_IMAGESIZE: google.search.ImageSearch.IMAGESIZE_LARGE,
                    layout: google.search.ImageSearch.LAYOUT_CLASSIC
                }
            };
            var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('013541292256706915053:xxxxxxxxxxx', customSearchOptions);
            customSearchControl.getImageSearcher.RESTRICT_IMAGESIZE = google.search.ImageSearch.IMAGESIZE_LARGE;
            var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
            options.setAutoComplete(true);
            customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
            customSearchControl.setOnKeepCallback(this, function (result) {
                // your customize javascript here
            }, '&nbsp;');
        },
        true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:
 customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(20);